# Which the best way to pass values of dynamically created checkboxes and groupboxes

Tags: c#-3.0

I am standing on a cross road with a doubt which way is the correct way. As you all are seeing the image Groupbox and CheckBoxes all are dynamically created. What I am confused about If user select Sun Tue and Fri from XII2013SIF01 and Mon Tue Wed and Thr from XII2013SIG02 how I can pass these check boxes value to Step 3 Form on button click. In Step 3 form I need to identify days by their Group name because according to that processing will be done. What technique will be best for me please give some guidance/suggestion or advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best is to create a class that will contain the data collected in this step (or in the whole sequence of steps). On that class, this specific list of choices can be represented as `HashSet<DayOfWeek>` property for each section.

Example with class per step:

```
public class Step2Selection {
   public Step2Selection() {
      XII2013SIF01 = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>();
      XII2013SIG02 = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>();
   }

   public HashSet<DayOfWeek> XII2013SIF01 { get; private set; }
   public HashSet<DayOfWeek> XII2013SIG02 { get; private set; }
}
```

Alternatively, if the number of sections can grow you may use a dictionary or list of custom section classes.

For your specific case, you can also use a dictionary without custom classes:

```
IDictionary<string, HashSet<DayOfWeek>> // where dictionary keys are "XII2013SIF01", etc
```

Though it will not scale well for any additional complexity.

Comment: @AndreyThank you. I used List<string> in Step1 to pass the groupBox names to the constructor of Step2 Form. And from Step2 I need both the groupbox and checkbox names respectively. And Yes Section(Groupbox) can increase. If list can do this then please just hold my fingure and show me the way I will try to walk on with the guidance and help of List<T>

Comment: @user2241865 I have added the minimal thing required (see Dictionary definition at the end).

Comment: Is List<> not proper for this, because I'm not that much comfortable with IDictionary